# Facebook Integration in android showing error while adding library

Tags: android, facebook

Am Doing Facebook Integration In Android. I did all the 5 steps given in the [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)
But When am doing 6th step i.e., Adding FacebookSDK to my Application I got Some Errors.
I posted those errors please help me out .....

`

```
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration] Versions found are:
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration] Path: C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration]   Length: 349252
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration]   SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration] Path: C:\ste\FbIntegration\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration]   Length: 385685
[2013-03-09 16:20:47 - FbIntegration]   SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy android-support-v4.jar

```
C:\Users\gtm\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
```

to

```
C:\ste\FbIntegration\libs\android-support-v4.jar
```

It is exactly what error says. There can be only one version of android-support-v4.jar in dependency

Comment: superb!! i was having the same issue, and this resolved perfect :-)